# Web Form Validator Layout Issue

Tags: asp.net

I have a Div that holds a RadioButtonList with 2 values and a required field validator.

[image]

As you can see the validator wraps to the next line (Circled). I am trying to get it to display next to the RadioButtonList (where the red dot is).  No matter what I do it remains on the next line.

I have made the cell wider with no effect.  I have set Display to Dynamic, no effect. With all the other controls on the form (textboxes & Drop downs) the validator displays correctly but this one wont.  It is the same in Design mode as it is when I run the app.

Comment: The design may differ on rendering engines, but you may expect the same rendering result on IE. How are you managing the site layout, are you using tables, DIVs or a CSS framework?

Comment: Its divs using `display: table;`, `display:  table-row;` & `display: table-cell;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the RadioButtonList I set RepeatDirection to Flow.  Its fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the size of the div where you place the radio button control is small.Can you please increase the size of that div.

Comment: I did say in the original question that I have already tried this.